# vbs macro Method Run of object 'IWshShell3' failed only chokes on larger Word files

Tags: vba, powershell, ms-word

I am really new to VBA. I've pasted only the last part of this sub, but can put the rest up if it helps.  Would appreciate any assist.  I've searched for days, but most issues with this error are caused by spaces in the path name.  Thank you extra!

This macro reads the header, then each table in the open Word document, then writes each line to the `htmlFile` variable.  It then runs the PowerShell ps1 file that writes the HTML file to the save path.

Works great on smaller Word docs, but when i run it on a larger ones, i get this error:

> Run-time error '-2147024690 (800700ce)': Method 'Run' of object
>   'IwshShell3' failed

Code (Everything in the Sub before this bit was reading each table in the open Word doc and writing to `htmlFile` as HTML code):

```vb
Sub WriteHtml()
    Dim htmlFile AS String, strText As String

    '
    ' fill htmlFile with HTML code ...

    htmlFile = htmlFile & strText

    Dim pwFileLocation, htmlFileLocation As String
    pwFileLocation = "'O:\Docketbk\DocketToWeb\processFile.ps1'"

    'htmlFileLocation = "'W:" & stringSplits(1) & "'"
    htmlFileLocation = "'Q:\OIT\Web Sites\This Site\Regulatory\Docketbk\" & stringSplits(1) & "'"
    fileNameFinal = Left(ActiveDocument.Name, InStrRev(ActiveDocument.Name, ".") - 1) & ".html"

    Dim shell, command1
    command1 = "powershell -noexit -command powershell.exe -Executionpolicy Bypass -File " & pwFileLocation & "-htmlContent ""'" & htmlFile & """' -savePath " & htmlFileLocation & " -fileName """ & fileNameFinal & """"
    Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    shell.Run command1, 1

End Sub
```

POWERSHELL CODE:

```
param(
   [string] $htmlContent,
   [string] $savePath,
   [string] $fileName
)
$fullFilePath = $savePath + "\" + $fileName 

Function CreateHtmlFile()
{
        if (!(Test-Path -Path $fullFilePath)){
            New-Item  $fullFilePath -ItemType File
            WriteHtmlFile       
        } else {
             WriteHtmlFile
        }
}
Function WriteHtmlFile()
{
        Set-Content $fullFilePath $htmlContent.Replace('$DubQ','"')     
}
createHtmlFile
```

POWERSHELL MOVE CODE:

```
param(
   [string] $oldFileLocation,
   [string] $newFileLocation
)

net use W: \\MYSERVERNAME\Websites\PUC\Regulatory\Docketbk

Function MoveFile
{
    $moveDirectory = $oldFileLocation + "/*" 
    Copy-Item -Path $MoveDirectory  -Destination $newFileLocation -Container -Recurse -force
}

MoveFile
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205975/discussion-on-question-by-bullseye-vbs-macro-method-run-of-object-iwshshell3-f).

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of keeping it simple. And most (if not all) of your issues seem to come from *not* keeping it simple. You have too many moving parts, too many levels of indirection. You can try to solve that by banging some more on it, our you can try to simplify your approach.

All you do – creating an HTML string, writing it to file, copying folders around – can be achieved in VBA code. I can't see anything that would require PowerShell.

For file system operations the `Scripting.FileSystemObject` is very handy, and the following code uses it. Let's make that available by **referencing** the "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" library via the Tools → References menu in the VBA IDE.

Now we have two basic operations, creating HTML from a source document, and writing a given text to a file.

```vb
Dim FSO As New Scripting.FileSystemObject

Function CreateHtml(sourceDoc As Document) As String
    ' Creates HTML from the tables of the given document.
    Dim html As String, text As String

    ' ... build html from sourceDoc
    html = html & text

    CreateHtml = html
End Function

Sub WriteTextToFile(content As String, path As String, Optional fileName As String)
    ' Writes a string to a Unicode file. Target will be overwritten if it exists.
    Dim targetPath As String

    If fileName > "" Then
        targetPath = FSO.BuildPath(path, fileName)
    Else
        targetPath = path
    End If

    With FSO.CreateTextFile(fileName:=targetPath, overwrite:=True, unicode:=True)
        .Write content
    End With
End Sub
```

And now we can combine those in a Sub I've called `HtmlWorkflow`, for lack of a better name:

```vb
Sub HtmlWorkflow()
    Dim stringSplits As Variant, html as String

    stringSplits = Split("something", "delimiter")
    html = CreateHtml(sourceDoc:=ActiveDocument)

    WriteTextToFile _
        content:=html, _
        path:="Q:\OIT\Web Sites\This Site\Regulatory\Docketbk\" & stringSplits(1), _
        fileName:=FSO.GetBaseName(ActiveDocument.Name) & ".html" _

    FSO.CopyFolder _
        Source:="Q:\whatever\your\source\folder\path\is", _
        Destination:="\\whatever\your\destination\folder\path\is"
End Sub
```

Notes:

- I'm using named parameters in my function calls - this can save some temporary variables and makes things basically self-documenting.
- `_` at the end of the line is VB's line-continuation character. Using it makes long lines of code easier to read.
- Breaking things up into separate functions makes it easier to debug & test (you can now call `CreateHtml()` against any open Document, no matter if it is active or not) and easy to re-use (`WriteTextToFile` does not care what file or what content).
- Documentation for the `FileSystemObject` is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/objects-visual-basic-for-applications

Comment: Wow, this looks so much cleaner.  I just need a little time to wrap my head around it, and get the folders source/destination set up properly.  Also unclear about the stringSplits line.  Thank you so much.  I will try to get this all in place in the morning.

Comment: Well I made up that line because your code was using `stringSplits(1)` and you never show what that even is. I figured it has to be some sort of string split operation, so I put in a dummy.

Comment: Confused as to where the Function CreateHtml goes.  Doesn't that have to be in a Sub?  Like i said, this is almost a foreign language and my version was cobbled together with great effort.  I feel like i am close.  The reason i even did it line by line was to clean up all the garbage Word HTML tags.  Does your way produce clean HTML?  Thanks again for the assist.

Comment: Create a new module in the VBA IDE and put the two functions from the first code snippet there. Or put them into the same module where your current code lives.

Comment: ...my second code snippet shows how the `CreateHtml()` function is supposed to be used. It has to be a `Function`, because it returns a value – an HTML string – and only functions can have return values in VBA.

Comment: Cleaning up the HTML that Word creates is not so easy. If you have that part working, keep it.

Comment: ...huh? How is the second block of code supposed to run when it calls functions from the first block of code? (Don't blindly copy and paste my code. Read & understand what it does. You need to understand each line of code you did not write yourself before you use it. Copypasting code you do not understand is dangerous.)